# Как получить двухмерный массив яркости пикселей из JPEG?

Tags: visual-c++

Имеется JPEG изображение, допустим, 25x25. Мне необходимо получить двумерный массив, в каждой ячейке которого будет содержаться яркость пикселя (в моем случае R = G = B = яркость, от 0 до 255).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для чтения jpeg потребуется какая-либо библиотека для работы с изображениями, которая загрузит файл и распакует сжатые данные в буфер пикселов. Например, при использовании [OpenCV](https://opencv.org) это будет выглядеть как

```
Mat mat = imread("filename.jpg");
```